# Weather forcasting: Error Property 'minutely' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, iot

I am having a problem with debugging this code. Basically, I am retrieving data from an API (openweathemap). In the console, everything looks fine. The data is generated, and I can even test it on localhost. But when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

*Property 'minutely' does not exist on type '{}'.*

```
import { HttpServer } from '@node-wot/binding-http'
import { Servient } from '@node-wot/core'
import fs = require('fs')
import axios from 'axios'
import { ThingDescription } from 'wot-typescript-definitions'

let td: ThingDescription
var forseenParameter: any = {}
var wateringON: any = {}

const delay = async (ms: number) => {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms))
}

async function getWeatherforseenParameter() {
    let ret = {}
    //const api_key = 'a8858df6f8baf4d469cdcd53d6865fecf'
    const api_key: string = 'c34aa6d1fb729b7c3784e97a778e3a7f'
    // HERE I chose unit as metric to get temperature in Celsius. 
    const api: string = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=48.14206178933707&lon=11.555223956707964&units=metric&appid=${api_key}`



    //let url: string = `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?lat=48.14206178933707&lon=11.555223956707964&key=${api_key}&include=${incl}`

    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(api)
        ret = await resp.data
        console.log(ret)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }

    return ret
}



async function isItWet(): Promise<boolean> {
    const forseenParameter = await getWeatherforseenParameter()
    if (forseenParameter.minutely[0].precipitation > 0) {
        return true
    } else if (wateringON) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
    return false
}

fs.readFile("myLovelyGarden.json", async (err, data) => {
    td = JSON.parse(data.toString());

    await main();
})

async function init() {
    const secInADay = 86400
    const d = new Date()
    const time_s = d.getSeconds() + 60 * d.getMinutes() + 60 * 60 * d.getHours()
    const forseenParameter = await getWeatherforseenParameter()
}

async function main() {
    const servient = new Servient()
    servient.addServer(new HttpServer())
    servient.start().then(async (WoT) => {
        let thing = await WoT.produce(td)
        await init()
    })
}
```

Here is the content of my package.json file:
{
"name": "Deliverable3-p1",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@node-wot/binding-coap": "0.7.4",
"@node-wot/binding-file": "0.7.4",
"@node-wot/binding-http": "0.7.4",
"@node-wot/core": "0.7.4",
"@types/node": "^14.0.23",
"axios": "^0.26.1",
"typescript": "^3.9.5"
}
}

And here is the content of tsconfig.json file:

{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"strict": true
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules"
],
"include": [
"*.ts"
]
}

Comment: You haven't given `ret` a type, so it's probably inferred as `{}`, resulting in an error.

Comment: @kellys thank you that was it. I may have overseen it while debugging and changing things in my code.